# Multi Select checkbox and dropdown option ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have 4 type of filters for my table filter by Date(usingdatepicker), Company Name(using multiselect dropdown checkbox), Age(using dropdown option) and Term(using dropdown option). Only the filter for CompanyName which using multiselect dropdown checkbox is not working WHEN i put function for the Age filter in the condition.

**index.php**

```
            <script>
        function getCOMPANY() {
            var form = document.frmSearch;
            var dataString = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){
                $("#company-list").html(data);
            }
            });
            return false;
        }
        </script>

        <script>
        function getDate(val) {
                $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "ajax.php",
                      data: 'from='+val,
                      defaultDate: "+1w",
                      success: function(data)
                      {
                         $("#company-list").html(data); //do something
                      }
                 });
             }
        </script>

        <script>
        function getTERM(val) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data:'terms='+val,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#company-list").html(data);
            }
            });
        }
        </script>

        <script>
        function getAGE(val){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data:'age='+val,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#company-list").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        </script>

        </head>
        <body class="reports" onload="calculateSum()">
        <div class="modal-body">    
            <div id="page-wrap">

                <br></br>

                <form name="frmSearch" id="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
                    <label>Date&nbsp;</label><input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="from" name="from" class="input-control" onChange="getDate(this.value);"/>

                    <label>Company Name&nbsp;</label>
                    <select id="multiple-checkboxes" multiple="multiple" onChange="return getCOMPANY();" name="COMPANYNAME[]" class="companyInput">
                    <?php
                        $query = mysqli_query($conn_connection, "SELECT * FROM sl_iv GROUP by COMPANYNAME");

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        echo "<option value='".$row["COMPANYNAME"]."'".($row["COMPANYNAME"]==$_POST["COMPANYNAME"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["COMPANYNAME"]."</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>

                    <label>Age&nbsp;</label>
                    <select name="age" id="age" onChange="getAGE(this.value);" class="companyInput">
                    <option value="10" id="more_than_10days" name="more_than_10days">=> 10 Days</option>
                    <option value="30" id="more_than_30days" name="more_than_30days">=> 30 Days</option>
                    </select>

                    <label>Term&nbsp;</label>
                    <select name="terms" id="terms" onChange="getTERM(this.value);" class="companyInput">
                    <option value="">Select Term</option>
                    <option value="C.O.D" id="cod" name="cod">COD</option>
                    <option value="30 Days" id="30days" name="30days">30 Days</option>
                    <option value="45 Days" id="45days" name="45days">45 Days</option>
                    </select>

                </form>
                    <br></br>

        <div name="state" id="company-list" class="companyInput">
                <table>
                    <center>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="15%" style="text-align:center"><span>Doc No.</span></th>
                            <th width="10%" style="text-align:center"><span>Date</span></th>
                            <th width="10%" style="text-align:center"><span>Terms</span></th>
                            <th width="10%" style="text-align:center"><span>Due</span></th>
                            <th width="5%" style="text-align:center"><span>Age</span></th>
                            <th width="20%" style="text-align:center"><span>Customer Name</span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    </center>

                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                        $docamt = $row['DOCAMT']; 
                        $paymentamt = $row['PAYMENTAMT'];
                        $outstanding = $docamt - $paymentamt;


                        $then = $row['DOCDATE'];
                        $then = strtotime($then);

                        $now = time();

                        $difference = $now - $then;
                        $dateage = floor($difference / (60*60*24));
                    ?>                
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" style="text-align:center; font-size:15px" class="form-control input-sm DocNo" id=DocNo0" name="DocNo" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['DOCNO']);?>" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="text" style="text-align:center; font-size:15px" class="form-control input-sm DocDate" id="DocDate0" name="DocDate" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['DOCDATE']);?>" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="text" style="text-align:center; font-size:15px" class="form-control input-sm Terms" id="Terms0" name="Terms" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['terms']);?>" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="text" style="text-align:center; font-size:15px" class="form-control input-sm DueDate" id="DueDate0" name="DueDate" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['DUEDATE']);?>" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="text" style="text-align:center; font-size:15px" class="form-control input-sm DateAge" id="DateAge0" name="DateAge" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($dateage);?>" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="text" style="text-align:center; font-size:15px" class="form-control input-sm CompanyName" id="CompanyName0" name="CompanyName" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['COMPANYNAME']);?>" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }
                    ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

**ajax.php**

```
                    <?php
                    if(!empty($_POST['COMPANYNAME']))
                    {
                        $COMPANYNAME = ($_POST);
                        $COMPANYNAME = $_POST['COMPANYNAME'];
                        $COMPANYNAME = is_array($COMPANYNAME) ? $COMPANYNAME : [$COMPANYNAME];

                        $companiesParam = '\''. join("', '", $COMPANYNAME) . '\'';
                        $fetch = "SELECT * FROM `sl_iv` Inner Join `ar_iv` On ar_iv.DOCNO = sl_iv.DOCNO Inner Join `payment_terms` On ar_iv.TERMS = payment_terms.id WHERE sl_iv.COMPANYNAME IN (".$companiesParam.")";
                        $results = mysqli_query($conn_connection,$fetch)or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn_connection) . "<hr>\nQuery: $fetch");   
                    }
                    if(!empty($_POST['terms']))
                    {
                        $terms = $_POST['terms'];
                        $fetch = "SELECT * FROM `sl_iv` Inner Join `ar_iv` On ar_iv.DOCNO = sl_iv.DOCNO Inner Join `payment_terms` On ar_iv.TERMS = payment_terms.id WHERE payment_terms.terms = '".$terms."'";
                        $results = mysqli_query($conn_connection,$fetch)or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn_connection) . "<hr>\nQuery: $fetch");
                    }
                    if(!empty($_POST['age']))
                    {
                        $age = $_POST['age'];
                        $fetch = "SELECT * FROM `sl_iv` Inner Join `ar_iv` On ar_iv.DOCNO = sl_iv.DOCNO Inner Join `payment_terms` On ar_iv.TERMS = payment_terms.id WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL '".$age."' DAY) >= sl_iv.DOCDATE";
                        $results = mysqli_query($conn_connection,$fetch)or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn_connection) . "<hr>\nQuery: $fetch");
                    }
                    if(!empty($_POST['from']))
                    {
                        $from = $_POST['from'];
                        $fetch = "SELECT * From `sl_iv` Inner Join `ar_iv` On ar_iv.DOCNO = sl_iv.DOCNO Inner Join `payment_terms` On ar_iv.TERMS = payment_terms.id WHERE sl_iv.DOCDATE <= '".$from."'";
                        $results = mysqli_query($conn_connection,$fetch)or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn_connection) . "<hr>\nQuery: $fetch");
                    }
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
```

Comment: There are multiple errors in your code. Two examples: 1. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. 2. You're using variables before they are defined Example: first query is using `$from`, which is defined further down.

Comment: Also make sure you have error reporting on and are displaying errors while you develop. Also check your error log. I'm sure you will have many error messages, which will help you debug your code and sort them out.

Comment: i saw alot of error especially with undefined index and variable in my code.

Comment: i done removing the error but the multiselect checkbox doesnt work.. no error found from reporting @Magnus Enksson

Comment: The issues I can find from your code like 1. DOM with id company-list is missing from your index.php 2. on ajax.php, you are returning no response.

Comment: I would suggest to use form.serialize and pass all parameter in post and make a single query for different parameters.

Comment: there compy-list i didnt post all code yet. when i remove the function getDateLess from ajax.php, every filter works fine only age filter doesnt work since i remove the function. diff things happening if i keep the function getDateLess where only the Companyname filter doesnt works others is works fine

Comment: I updated the code already but still didnt found the solution.. if i remove the if statement for the age in ajax.php, others filter working fine except the age filter. when i put back the if statement for the age in ajax.php, others filter is working except the COMPANYNAME (multiselect checkbox) is not working.